# tikz and new environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments, tikz-matrix

I would like to creat a new environment in order to draw the following matrix :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-8pt},every left delimiter/.style={xshift=8pt}]
  \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)](m)
  {
 a  \\
 b \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thus I would like the environment be :

```
\begin{mymatrix}
     a  \\
     b \\
\end{mymatrix}
```

However, I do not succeed in making it. Do you know how to proceed ?

Regards

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Addon: Your example is at least missing `\usetikzlibrary{matrix}` for the `matrix of math nodes` to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to grab the environment body as a macro argument so:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{mymatrix}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-8pt},every left delimiter/.style={xshift=8pt}]
  \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),
  ampersand replacement=\&](m)
  {\BODY};\end{tikzpicture}}


\begin{document}

\begin{mymatrix}
     a  \\
     b \\
\end{mymatrix}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Also `ampersand replacement=\&` should be added to the options for `\matrix` and `\&` for column separator in the body of the matrix.

Comment: @egreg happy now?

Comment: Why do you add `ampersand replacement=\&` ?

Comment: @hindi I always do what egreg tells me:-) (you don't need it in this one column case but would if you had more columns)